# Spring / Java call variable from one method as a Variable

Tags: java, sql, spring, jsp, web

I have a variable I'm calling "UtilityStartDate", lets just say it's in Class 1, and it pulls the value from a Stored Proc.

Class 1

```
 @Override
    public void populateUtility(Date utilityStartDate, String utilityStatus) {
        if(this.Utility != null) {
            this.Utility.populate(utilityStartDate, utilityStatus);
        }
    }
```

I wanted to populate it here, in a different class (Class 2), where currently it's using a constant. "READ_DASHBOARD_START_DATE", also used as "dateFrom". 
Class 2

```
        @Loggable(value = LogLevel.DEBUG)
    public List <MeterReadChart> populateMeterReadChart(String customerId) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String dateTo = DateUtils.formatDate(cal.getTime());
        **cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, Constant.READ_DASHBOARD_START_DATE);
        String dateFrom = DateUtils.formatDate(cal.getTime());**

        return meterReadingDao.populateMeterReadingDetail(customerId, dateFrom, dateTo);

    }
```

I'm VERY new to java/spring, and not sure how to go and call it from Class 1, to the Method in Class 2

Comment: try annotating then as `@Component`, and then you can use `@Autowired` to inject one into the other, if I know correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reference of Class1 into Class2 by using Spring IOC.

```
Class Class1 
    {

     // Populated value to be stored
     private Date utilityStartDate;

    // method called by Class2 to get the populated value
     public Date getUtilityStartDate()
    {
        return utilityStartDate;
     }

   // Method to populated. (Your logic)
   @Override
   public void populateUtility(Date utilityStartDate, String utilityStatus) {
    if(this.Utility != null) {
        this.Utility.populate(utilityStartDate, utilityStatus);
       }
    }

  }

    Class Class2
    {
     private Class1 class1;

     public void setClass1(Class1 class1)
     {
        this.class1 = class1;
     }


    @Loggable(value = LogLevel.DEBUG)
    public List <MeterReadChart> populateMeterReadChart(String customerId) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String dateTo = DateUtils.formatDate(cal.getTime());
        **cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, Constant.READ_DASHBOARD_START_DATE);**
        // getting Date from Class1
        String dateFrom = DateUtils.formatDate(class1.getUtilityDate());

            return meterReadingDao.populateMeterReadingDetail(customerId, dateFrom, dateTo);

        }
    }
```